# trying to add database to working table view app with no luck

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, plist

I have a working app which is a table view app and I'm trying to store my table view to a database. I've searched google but I couldn't find anything helpful! All the tutorials I've found are tutorials for building apps from scratch. I just want to update mine!
So here is my basic class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Movie : NSObject
{
    NSString *_title;
    NSString *_gender;
    NSString *_location;
    NSNumber *_publicationYear;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *gender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *publicationYear;

+ (id)movieWithTitle:(NSString *)title
             gender:(NSString *)gender
               year:(NSUInteger)year
            location:(NSString *)location;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
             gender:(NSString *)gender
               year:(NSUInteger)year
            location:(NSString *)location;

@end
```

What I want to do is create a database and store "title", "gender", "year" and "location" and then make them appear in my table view.

Any help will be great. Thanks in advance. If there is anything else you want me to post for making it easier to answer please notify me.

Answer (score 0):

just fetch allData from sqlite & assign them to your Movie object. make aray of Movie object & use it in to your tableview :)

Answer (score 0):

See [this fantastic tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app) from Ray Wenderlich which'll teach you everything you need to know about adding SQLite to your app.

Comment: thanks for the post!i read the tutorial. its a nice one but i'm trying to to do the opposite! the tutorial shows you how to populate a database to a table view. i want to fill up an empty database from the table view... :(

Comment: Whilst it indeed doesn't show you how to save data, it still must be useful on some level? Surely once you've got the data saved, you'll want to reload and display it? It also demonstrates some common concepts such as linking to the SQLite library, creating a new database, locating it on the file system, opening it in memory etc, all of which you need to know and implement regardless of whether you're loading or saving data.